# MISRA CPP 2008, order of evaluation

Tags: c++, c++11, misra

While reading MISRA CPP 2008, I have stumbled upon the following example:

```
x = b[i] + i++;
```

this example shows that order of evaluation can affect result, and there is undefined behavior due to 2 ways are possible:

- 1.b[i] then i++
- 2.i++ then b[i]

as far as I remember from CS courses - i will be incremented only after the whole expression evaluation, is that true?
If so could you please provide me with the reference to relevant info in the standard?

Comment: It is not UB because of 2 possible evaluation orders (that would be *unspecified behaviour*). It is UB because there's no sequence point between modifying and reading `i`.

Comment: *"is that true?"* - No, it is not.

Comment: i++ will: fetch i and save it for later, increment i, return the saved value from before. This may happen before b[i] is evaluated

Comment: C++ Standard: Have a look at 4.6.17 (C alike, by the way, 6.5.2...).